# Basic Probability of multiple independent events and Gambler's Fallacy

Tags: probability, independence, gambling

I am trying to understand some basic probability concepts, so I am writing up my understanding here and would appreciate feedback on anything wrong so I can learn from it.

Classic Roulette example:

- guy witnesses black come up 5 times
- he bets on red thinking it is more likely
- he is wrong because of gambler's fallacy

I have seen this explained as simply this:  Since each spin is independent of each other spin, black and red are equally likely and he succumbed to "The Gambler's Fallacy."  In the example, they will typically show the gambler goof by assuming that red has a 1/64th chance of coming up when in reality, they imply that the chance is 1/2.

What gets interesting though is exactly what mistake is our gambler making?

If I wanted to bet on getting 5 blacks and one red coming up specifically on six spins versus betting on getting 6 blacks in six spins, what is the probability of each occurrence?

I think for that specific event, we calculate it as the gambler did: 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 *1/2 *1/2 = 1/64th.

But where he is going wrong is that the combination of all 6 blacks holds the same probability: 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 *1/2 *1/2 = 1/64th.  So neither event is any more likely.

And if we the add all the possible combinations of 6 spins ending in red or black, we would see that it simplifies to 1/2 which might help the gambler see his mistake.  There should be 32 possible combinations of six spins ending in red and 32 possible combinations of six spins ending in black.

Then we can point out that his gamble is not truly on all six spins, but only this spin.  Which means that because these are independent events, he should really ignore the past and see this spin as simply 1/2.

Is this interpretation correct?  Is there anything in this write-up that needs correcting or further explanation?  Please advise.

Comment: Looks perfectly OK to me :) Ignoring the fact that there's that pesky green which is how the casinos make their money -- the mistake our gambler is making is playing roulette in the first place!

Comment: Well that's an error in judgement and a failure of wisdom.  His calculation is the logic error.  :-)

Comment: Yes, I think the essence of your point was made near the end, which was that looking back is irrelevant when evaluating independent events (at least when you understand the probabilities at work). Prior instances are _independent_ from future ones.